# String array not serialized to json properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Trying to pass some JSON to my view.

In Controller:

```
var array = new string[] {"123", "AAA"};
string jsonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array);
ViewBag.JsonDataLabels = jsonArray;
```

In the view's script:

```
var jLabels = '@ViewBag.JsonDataLabels';
```

But this json seems to be somewhat invalid. 
Eg if I do this in the script:

```
var jLabels = '@ViewBag.JsonDataLabels';
alert(jLabels); // OUTPUT KO : [&quot;123&quot;,&quot;AAA&quot;]
var jLabels2 = ["AAA", "123"];
alert(jLabels2); // OUTPUTS OK : AAA, 123
```

Why is my JSON invalid?

Comment: On the controller code, `jsonLabels` is not defined, did you mean `ViewBag.JsonDataLabels = jsonArray` ?

Comment: It is HTML encoding the string, I think you will need something like `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.JsonDataLabels)`

Comment: Also, don't have quotes around your value in Javascript: `var jLabels = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.JsonDataLabels);`

Comment: @tianvh or write `var jLables = JSON.parse("@Html.Raw(ViewBag.JsonDataLabels)");` I know that InteliiSense likes to complain when razor syntax is used in JS without qoutes (but only InteliiSense, it compiles fine :) )

Comment: @BenRobinson tianvh thanks to both of you it works now. Post it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze this (sample from newtonsoft website)

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small"
//  ]
//}
```

for your expected result use var array = new {"123", "AAA"};